Tip for optimal FW configuration (Iptables)
This is my Iptables configuration:
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:port-scan - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -j LOG
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -j DROP
-A port-scan -m limit --limit 1/sec --limit-burst 4 -j RETURN

Any suggestions to improve or remove useless rules?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Are you having any specific problems you feel or know are related to this config? This site is about specific problems. Asking for general suggestions and tips isn't bad, but it is not right for this site, and should be done on another forum.

When your policy of a basic chain is drop (:INPUT DROP [0:0]), there is no point in appending drop rules to the base chain, unless you need to "subtract" part of an accept rule.
For example, if you want to accept all inbound ICMP traffics but those of "type 8" (whatever that means):
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

Note that reject rules, such as those with -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable, is not the same thing as drop rules. I am not going to dive into the details of when you may want to reject traffics instead of just dropping it, or what rejecting means, rather my point is, if you want to reject certain traffics instead of dropping them, you will need a rule even when the chain policy is drop.
Since you do not have any relevant accept rules appended (after) these rules:
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP

none of them matter.
I don't know if any of those TCP-flags-checking rules could make any sense under any circumstances, but if you really want to apply them to e.g. the -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 traffics, the correct way to do it is you add those drop rules to a new chain (instead of a base chain), for example named TCP_FC, and then replace the -j ACCEPT with -g TCP_FC, with a fallback -j ACCEPT appended to TCP_FC at the end:
-N TCP_FC
-A TCP_FC -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
...
-A TCP_FC -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A TCP_FC -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -g TCP_FC

When the "destination" chain has a fallback rule (e.g. unconditional -j ACCEPT or -j DROP at the end), it doesn't matter if you use -j or -g to make matched traffics to traverse the chain, like in the example above, -j TCP_FC is fine as well.

Note that when you have:
-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

in a chain, such as INPUT, any accept rule that consists of the same match, such as,
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

is useless (-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED is like a shorter version of -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED), because "accept any A" "covers" "accept any A AND B".
In other words, if you really just want to accept some of the RELATED,ESTABLISHED traffics, then you should not have the rule that accepts all of them. And if you yet want to "optimize" something like:
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --sports 53 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
...

you can have something like:
-N ACCEPT_RE
-A ACCEPT_RE -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A ACCEPT_RE -p udp --sports 53 -j ACCEPT
...
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -g ACCEPT_RE

Note the -g in the last rule, which means if some traffic is matched by this rule and hence "goto" the chain specified (ACCEPT_RE), but it is not further matched by any rule in the that chain, it will not traverse any later rule in the chain that contains the rule that has the -g. (When there is only one additional layer of chain, such as the example here, it means that the fate of the traffic will be determined by the chain policy of the base chain, namely DROP of INPUT.) As mentioned earlier, you may also append a fallback drop rule to the end of ACCEPT_RE, then -j ACCEPT_RE would be fine as well.
Alternatively, you may as a whole have something like this instead:
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m state ! --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -j ACCEPT

Note that the -i lo accept rule has been "moved up" to retain the same effect it has in the original rule set -- any -i lo traffic should be accepted regardless of its state.
The reject rule for -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 has been moved up as well so that such traffic will be rejected instead of dropped regardless of its state.
By "early" dropping any other traffic of state other than (note the !) RELATED or ESTABLISHED, namely those of the state NEW or INVALID, you can have accept rules after the drop rule that accept e.g. -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 traffics without having to specify the same state check again and again, because only traffics that "got through" the drop rule would be able to "reach" the accept rule(s) that follows. In other words, to state the obvious, no -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 traffics of state NEW or INVALID would be accepted because of the respective accept rule (that is appended after state-checking drop rule).

The (conntrack) state check in this rule is useless:
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

because you have before it:
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Technically having the state check would make sure that INVALID outbound traffics destined at any of those two port numbers will not be accepted (because of that rule), but I doubt that in reality it makes any sense (or that the state could even be INVALID at all). (Either way, only NEW is needed.)

Also note that this rule will not be used at all:
-A port-scan -m limit --limit 1/sec --limit-burst 4 -j RETURN

since no traffic would be made to traverse to the port-scan chain (i.e., neither -j port-scan nor -g port-scan is used in any rule). Besides, the effect of RETURN highly depends on the "structure" of your rule set.

In case what you want is to log all inbound traffics, the (unconditional) -j LOG rule need to be the first rule in the INPUT chain. Traffics matching an earlier rule that has a terminating target (such as ACCEPT, DROP and REJECT; in some cases RETURN could be effectively terminating as well) will never reach it otherwise.

P.S. This answer does NOT serve the purpose of providing a sensical rule set. It purely uses the rule set in the question as an example to showcase the "logic" of iptables. In other words it offers only some of the fundamentals of how a (relatively) "neat" rule set could be written, but not what rules should a rule set has (partly because that requires context).
Also, "optimizations" with attempt to speculate/deduce the context (or "full picture") were not necessarily included. For example,
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -j ACCEPT

is also useless when it really just serves as the "complement" for:
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT

when there is already:
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


FWIW, I have no problem browsing websites with the following filter table:
$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.10 on Tue Nov  5 06:07:17 2024
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Nov  5 06:07:17 2024

With that said, it does NOT mean it will always work. For example, if you bring up a wireguard tunnel with an endpoint that is configured to be effectively the "default gateway", certainly the above won't be sufficient (unless maybe if your wireguard "server" listens on UDP port 53).
